# Libvirt and virtualbox, no way to start vm?

Tags: virtualbox, libvirt

I have configured a fedora server (36)
and I have installed libvirt, virtualbox, and other daemons

```
virtualbox-guest-additions-6.1.40-1.fc36.x86_64
libvirt-daemon-driver-vbox-8.1.0-2.fc36.x86_64
VirtualBox-6.1-6.1.40_154048_fedora36-1.x86_64
```

I have configured correctly the virtvboxd daemon, my user can see the vm configured

```
virsh -c vbox:///session list  --all

 Id   Name   State
-----------------------
 -    vbox   shut off
```

But when I start...

```
virsh start --domain vbox 
error: Failed to start domain 'vbox'
error: operation failed: OpenRemoteSession/LaunchVMProcess failed, domain can't be started
```

Why?
I have tried 2 different xml, the second is copied from libvirt site!

myxml [1](https://pastebin.com/8Hjd3k8f)

xmlcopied [2](https://pastebin.com/14Pn6iMZ)

This is the debug [3](https://pastebin.com/SaFxGGrM)

p.s= I don't use qemu even is better supported, because my emulated vm needs buslogic controller and only VirtualBox can run it (Interactive Unix 4.1.1)

Comment: can you run `vbox` VMs manually without libvirt? The libvirt log doesn't tell us anything – it's VirtualBox that fails.

Comment: Without libvirt I can run virtualbox sucessfully from the gui.